# How to find places near by given lat/lng location

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I've a list of lat/lng (Restaurants), i wish to find out those restaurants(from my list) near by a given location, let's say 2km in circle.

I don't need to know the actual Distance, so the **Haversine** function is not required here.

And because i only interested in short distance, basically we can assume the earth is flat, pole and degree maybe is not important here.

Low accuracy is acceptable too.

What is the most efficient way to do this in **Javascript**?

lat lng is in decimal format (-27.55097,135.458679)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *Apologies— I misunderstood the question. I thought you already had a list of restaurants, and you wanted to find others, nearby, not the distance from one to another.*

---

Google's got your back (as always): Check out the [Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), and the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), in particular.

The `nearbySearch` method accepts an object that may contain the `types` key. It should contain an array of [Place type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) slugs, one of which happens to be `restaurant`.

Be sure to also pass the `bounds` or `location` and `radius` keys in the request object to fetch results only within a certain area.